# How to split list item to lists that start with specific value?

Tags: c#

I have following list.

```
var mainList = new List<string>
{ "Reset","Set","Test","Test","Reset","Test","Test"};
```

I'd like to split this mainList to two lists that each list starts "Reset".
Like,

```
{ "Reset","Set","Test","Test"} and {"Reset","Test","Test"}
```

How to split list?

Comment: Is the input format fixed? I mean will it be always List?

Comment: Yes, it's always List.

Comment: Try my solution and check if works for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following solution assume that you are splitting before "Reset" text, so if first field is not "Reset" then it will skip all elements until "Reset" is found.

```
  public static List<List<string>> Split(this List<string> list, string splitter)
        {
            var _list = new List<List<string>>();
            var count = list.Count(x => x == splitter);
            list.ForEach(item =>
            {
                if(item == splitter)
                {
                    _list.Add(new List<string>());
                }
                _list.LastOrDefault()?.Add(item);
            });
            return _list.ToList();
        }
```

Usage

```
 var mainList = new List<string>
                          { "Set","Test","Test","Reset","Test","Test"};
 var res = mainList.Split("Reset");
```

Comment: Thanks A.T.! It works well and it's good to give "splitter" as an argument.

Comment: please mind Null-conditional Operator I used, its c# 6 feature https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn986595.aspx

Comment: Thanks, in my develop environment allows to use c# 6 feature.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand it correctly you want to do something like this

```
var mainList = new List<string> { "Reset", "Set", "Test", "Test", "Reset", "Test", "Test" };
List<string> jask = new List<string>();
List<string> jask1 = new List<string>();
jask = mainList.Take(4).ToList();
jask1 = mainList.Skip(4).ToList();
```

Later I got that you want to split it by "Reset" than you can do it like this

```
var mainList = new List<string> { "Reset", "Set", "Test", "Test", "Reset", "Test", "Test" };
List<string> jask = new List<string>();
string ksjd =  string.Join(",", mainList.ToArray());
jask = Regex.Split(ksjd, @"(?=Reset)").Skip(1).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Mohit. The position of "Reset" is not fixed. So your answer doesn't apply when the index of "Reset" is changed. .

Comment: Your second method will result as `IEnumerable<string>` with `"Reset,Set,Test,Test,", "Reset,Test,Test"` data; that is not what OP wanted ;).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a Dictionary here to get the result groups, something like the following:

```
var mainList = new List<string> { "Reset", "Set", "Test", "Test", "Reset", "Test", "Test" };
Dictionary<int, List<string>> resultList = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
int DictionaryIndex = 0;
foreach (string item in mainList)
{
    if (item == "Reset")
    {
        resultList.Add(++DictionaryIndex, new List<string>() { item });
    }
    else
    {
        resultList[DictionaryIndex].Add(item);
    }
}
```

The `resultList` will contains the separated list as you needed. You can take a look into this [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xfb1ea) and let me know whether it satisfies your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4bkxt7(v=vs.110).aspx

// pseudocode

```
while (index < len)
{
  int nextOccurence = arrayList.IndexOf(delimeterString, index)
  output.Add (arrayList.GetRange(index, nextOccurence))
  index = nextOccurence + 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

look

```
var mainList = new List<string> { "Reset", "Set", "Test", "Test", "Reset",        "Test", "Test" };
        var lastIndex = mainList.FindLastIndex(x => x.Equals("Reset"));
        var firstList = new List<string>();
        var secondList = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mainList.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i < lastIndex)
            {
                firstList.Add(mainList[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                secondList.Add(mainList[i]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
public static void SplitList()
    {
        var mainList = new List<string> { "Reset", "Set", "Test", "Test", "Reset", "Test", "Test" };

        List<List<string>> lstOutputLists = new List<List<string>>();
        List<string> tmp = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in mainList)
        {
            if (item == "Reset")
            {
                if (tmp.Count != 0)
                {
                    lstOutputLists.Add(tmp);
                    tmp = new List<string>();    
                }

            }
            tmp.Add(item);
        }
        lstOutputLists.Add(tmp);
    }
```

lstOutputLists will give you the output..

Comment: Thanks A3006! I got lists using your SplitList(). It can work well if the mainList have more elements!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var result = string
    .Join("|", mainList)
    //     ^ use a special character/pattern that will never use in your texts
    .Replace("Reset", "|@|Reset")
    //                 ^^^ use a special pattern for identifying place of `Reset`  
    .Split(new [] { "|@|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    // at first I split by place of `Reset` to create a list of strings that identifies by `|@|`
    .Select(c => c.Split(new[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    // now each string will become a list of strings
    .ToList();
```

### [`[ C# Demo ]`](http://ideone.com/OOoIE4)

---

In a LinQ-full mode, I can also suggest this:
Note: Thjis method works similar to `Partition By` in SQL.

```
var i = 1;
var result = mainList
    .Select(str =>
    {
        if (str == "Reset") i++;
        return new { str, i };
    })
    //  ^^ Above I make partitions by `i`; that `i` will change by watching a `Reset`
    .GroupBy(g => g.i)
    .Select(g => g.Select(c => c.str).ToList());
    // then I just group by `i` as partition then removing it from results.
```

### [`[ C# Demo ]`](http://ideone.com/0n1jOP)